# Using onload to create CSS fallback for Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, cdn, fallback

I'm attempting to create CSS fallbacks for CDNS using the onload event in Internet Explorer, but I'm having issues getting it to work. The onerror version works fine for Chrome and Firefox. I'm trying to set the variable linkSuccess to false and use the onload event to change linkSuccess to true when the stylesheet loads. If the onload event doesn't fire, linkSuccess should stay false run the fallback. But I'm having trouble getting it to work.

Any help you can provide is appreciated! Thanks!

```
<!-- CDNs for Bootstrap and Font-Awesome -->
<link id="bootstrapFallback" onError="stylesheetFallback(this.id)" onLoad="ieFallbackCheck(this.id)" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1./css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link id="fontAwesomeFallback" onError="stylesheetFallback(this.id)" onLoad="ieFallbackCheck(this.id)" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

fallback.js Code:

```
var cssFallbacks = {
  "bootstrapFallback" : "/bootstrap.min.css",
  "fontAwesomeFallback" : "/font-awesome.min.css"
};

var linkSuccess = false;

function stylesheetFallback(fallbackKey) {
  document.getElementById(fallbackKey).href = cssFallbacks[fallbackKey];
}

function ieFallbackCheck(fallbackKey) {
    var linkSuccess = true;
}

if (linkSuccess = false) {
    document.getElementById("bootstrapFallback").href = cssFallbacks[bootstrapFallback];
    console.log("Initiate Fallback");
}
```

Comment: "having trouble getting it to work"... what does that mean? Please take a look at [ask]. You need to [edit] your answer with more information about what you're expecting to happen, what actually happens, and any errors you get in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) for CSS fallbacks:

```
<link href="original-styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<link href="ie6-fix.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<![endif]-->
```

The link in the comment will only be interpreted by IE 8 and bellow.